# Styling action bar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to style an action bar that has two menu icons on it. I am using the `AppCompat` theme, and I have 4 fragments in the app. I don't want to use a toolbar for this.

Here is what I have so far. This styles the bar color and text color, but the overflow menu (3 dots) and up arrow icons don't change color, only the text and background.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>        
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>        
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.Theme.OverflowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @Drenmi Correct my code by all means  but if you are going to correct peoples grammar get it right, Here what I have so far , is not what I wrote. And why take out the mannerly polite any help appreciated comment ? .

Comment: To be fair, I did not edit that part. There were two edits applied to this post. :-) Manners are certainly a good thing, but similar frills are frequently edited out, as they do not add to the substance of the question. I think we can imply that everyone is grateful for the help they get here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer to the style `Your.Theme.OverflowStyle` anywhere in `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>`.

Having something like the following should work.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Your.Theme.OverflowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Off-topic suggestion: Do not have so many empty lines in your code. It is harder to read, since it is harder to detect the logical code groups.

Comment: Thanks @dnzprmksz , didnt quite fix it for me but I have found a solution see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution that worked for me.I had to download the navigation icon and vertical menu icon.Hope this makes sense , no doubt the grammar nazis will be out.

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButton</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButton</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
    </style>
    <style name="OverflowButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_18dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text </item>
    </style>


</resources>
```